# Solving $x^3+y^3+z^3= 2014^{2012}$ over the integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, diophantine-equations

> Prove that the equation  $x^3+y^3+z^3= 2014^{2012}$ doesn't have integer solutions.

How does one come up with the idea of using congruences modulo $9$?

Comment: Because $\phi(9)=2\cdot 3$, it follows that $t^3\equiv 0,\pm1 \pmod{9}$.  If you see a power $k$ in a diophantine equation, you might want to find a small natural number $n$ s.t. $k\mid \phi(n)$ so that there are not so many residues of $t^k$ mod $n$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool could you post this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\phi(9)=2\cdot 3$, it follows that $t^3\equiv 0,\pm1 \pmod{9}$.  If you see a power $k$ in a diophantine equation, you might want to find a small natural number $n$ s.t. $k\mid \phi(n)$ so that there are not so many residues of $t^k$ mod $n$.  Usually, we only look for an integer $n$ which is a prime power.

Here are some related questions that can be solved by using the paragraph above.

- Find all integers $x$, $y$, and $z$ s.t. $x^3+y^3=z^6+3$.  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292195/solving-the-diophantine-equation-x3y3-z63).)
- Find all integers $x$ and $y$ s.t. $x^5-3y^5=2008$.  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730908/no-integer-solutions-for-x5-3y5-2008).)
- Find all integers $x$ and $y$ s.t. $x^3+117y^3=5$.  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425986/prove-that-the-equation-x3-117y3-5-has-no-integer-solution-x-y/2426239#2426239).)
- Find all integers $x$ and $y$ s.t. $7x^3+2=y^3$.  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628711/solve-7x32-y3-over-integers/628713#628713).)
- Find all integers $x$ and $y$ s.t. $x^4-y^4=1996$.  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852929/prove-that-x4-y4-1996-has-no-integer-root/1852933#1852933).)

Answer (score 3):

Since $k=2014^{2012}\equiv 4\bmod 9$, we know that $k$ cannot be represented as the sum of three cubes - see 
[The sum of three cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523130/the-sum-of-three-cubes).